# How to optimize multiple if statements in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

This is my code :

```
Function CleanUpOracle 
{

    if ($Requete)
    {
        $Requete.Dispose()
    }

    if ($ExecuteRequete)
    {
        $ExecuteRequete.Dispose()
    }

    if ($Transaction)
    {
        $Transaction.Dispose()
    }

    if ($OracleConnexion)
    {
        $OracleConnexion.close()
        $OracleConnexion.Dispose()
    }

    if ($Log.id)
    {

        $Log.PSObject.Properties.Remove('id')

    }

}
```

I'm testing if a variable exist then `{do something}`

But in the future I'll many variable to test, I don't want to have hundred lines with that.

How can I optimize this? Maybe with a switch but how?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

If you want to conditionally call `Dispose` against multiple items you can stream them from a list into the [ForEach-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx) (whose alias is `%`):

```
@($Requete, $ExecuteRequete, $Transaction, $OracleConnexion) |
% {if($_) {$_.Dispose()} }
```

NOTE: I've split this onto multiple lines for readability.

Comment: Nice, but in some case in need to Close() or PSObject.Properties.Remove() also. How to differentiate easily?

Comment: @AdeelASIF - that's more difficult. However, most objects that have a `Close` method do the same when calling `Dispose`, so that may be something you can take advantage of.